# How to create a function and call its methods without using new, similar to jQuery $?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `$` of jQuery is a function, however you can access its methods as if it were an object through the `"."` . Could someone explain, in what way could I do this in a function `func` for example?

[image]

More clearly, I intend to use `func ()` as well as `func.each ()` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In javascript, functions are objects, you can attach properties to them:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log("foo is called!");
}

foo.prop = "Hello, world!";

foo.boo = function() {
    console.log("foo.boo is called!");
}

foo();                  //=> "foo is called!"
console.log(foo.prop);  //=> "Hello, world!"
foo.boo();              //=> "foo.boo is called!"
```

**Note:** One little note though, `$.each !== $(...).each`. The first is a property under `$`, while the latter belongs to jQuery's prototype. They're two different functions (although the one in the prototype calls the other one to do the job, but they are totally different).